# Android app with Preconfigured DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a CRUD Android app as a learning PoC with a pre-created SQLite DB using [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) blog entry, and it's working fine for reading data, but even when I try to open this DB in Read/Write mode, I'm getting trouble inserting data. The error message is that I'm attempting to insert records into a read-only DB. Could anyone please help me out? Is there any refactoring I need to do to the previously mentioned blog entry?

I apologise in advance of my post is a little half-baked. I'll try to provide clarifications if required.

Thanks,
Debojit

Comment: can you post your insert code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how you open the database.  You must be opening it read only.  Change the open method to `getWritableDatabase` and your error should go away.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Also, I'd done the extremely intelligent thing of opening a _readonly_ db on my `onResume` _after_ I'd called a read/write db in `onCreate`, so even when I'd done as you asked, I was getting the same error. I've removed db opening from `onCreate` into `onResume` only, now.

Comment: I've had days like that.  Glad you got it sorted.